# Spring Batch, Boot, JNDI and still conflicts with the transactionManager bean name

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, spring-batch, jndi, jta

I have configured Spring Batch, Boot (2.1.4) to retrieve the transaction manager from JBoss via JNDI and I still have conflicts with the transactionManager bean name, is it possible that every time it is always the same story but for different reasons?

Now the message is:

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Application failed to start due to an exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] for bean 'transactionManager': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JndiJtaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/jta/JndiJtaConfiguration.class]] bound.
```

Spring batch doesn't work with a transactional manager retrieved via JNDI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your transaction manager a name other than `transactionManager` because `@EnableBatchProcessing` already exposes a bean with that name (this is mentioned in the Javadoc of the annotation).

Comment: Hi, Mohmoud I had seen the javdoc and so I did, but is there no other way? Rewriting all JndiJtaConfiguration just for a bean name I don't consider it useful. Thanks

Comment: I understand. This is a known issue (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/816) and has been fixed in v5.

Comment: Really good news! Then I'll have to wait for our migration to v5 :(